# Spyder console breakdown

Tags: console, spyder

Quick question - do you know what to do if my console constantly stalls and I cant get out apart from closing and reopening the console? it happens only when debugger line is activated (import pdb; pdb.set_trace()). Stall is happening once some debugger operation finishes. after I type the next command in the debugger line - i cant hit enter. I can move my cursor in the debugger command line but otherwise it is not responding even to forced keyboard commands Contrl-C.  I can only close console and reopen - and even then it takes 10 seconds delay. To do it 50 times - a bit annoying.  no answers on internet. did submit feedback to spyder but no answer so far. Any hints you might have?

Comment: I responded you yesterday, you haven't responded back.

Comment: Dear Carlos, please excuse me but I cant find where did you respond? My mail is also empty

Comment: I responded on the Github issue you opened with the exact same problem.

Comment: Got it. I did respond back just now asking if there is a way to share it in email or other way

Comment: Dear Carlos, I did reply in github. The issue is with Cntrl-C which I use to copy data but in Kernel it is used to halt Kernel. Using Cntrl-Shift-C would avoid this contradiction. I got one-two questions about Spyder specifics - is there a way I can address you these questions? Thank you

Comment: If they don't involve things about your code/work, you could open a new question here (better) or an issue at Github (not so good, because that's to report problems)